# Ajax call returns undefined data after second try

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC3 and C#, the first time I make the call everything works fine, but the second time the parameters caught by C# action method are null.

This is my code:

```
Monitor.SearchAction = function (pageNum) {
var searchUrl = $("#textURL").data("url");
var newPageNum = pageNum;

var searchInput =
{
    PageNumber: newPageNum
};

searchInput["FromDate"] = $("#FromDate").val();
searchInput["FromHour"] = $("#FromHour").val();

$.ajax({
    url: searchUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(searchInput),
    success: function (d, m, x) {
        var $listingContainer = $("#listingContainer");
        $listingContainer.html(d);
    },
    async: false,
    cache: false,
});
};
```

Here is the controller method header:

```
public PartialViewResult Search  (DAS.Dashboard.Web.Areas.Monitoring.ViewModels.MonitoringSearchInputModel searchInput)
```

So, "searchInput" is a model with three attributes which are received "null" the second time it is called.

Comment: It would help to also show how this is being called.

Comment: Without knowing how searchUrl and searchInput get populated and what the values are, there is no way to diagnose this.

Comment: have you even tried basic troubleshooting by logging those values to console to see what they are?

Comment: Up to the line "data: JSON.stringify(searchInput)" I find that the info submitted is there, the problem is this info gets lost right in the middle before it gets to the C# method. It works fine the first time but the second time parameters are null.

Answer (score 0):

Check the partial view which being returned from the called C# method. i.e.

```
public PartialViewResult Search  (DAS.Dashboard.Web.Areas.Monitoring.ViewModels.MonitoringSearchInputModel searchInput)
```

If the partial view is having "FromDate" and "FromHour" input fields and with same attributes as having first time.

Comment: Thanks, the first time they have the values they are supposed to, the second time they are null.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem. Using the Chrome debugger I found that the first time the request was sent it's type was "POST", and by the second it was "GET" (Don't really know why this was hapenning).

But adding "type:'POST'" as well as "contentType: 'application/json'; charset=utf-8'" fixed the problem.

Thank you all.